# Why don't i have scope to access values in a recursiveDirectoryItorator?

Tags: php, iterator, scope

I'm playing around with the PHP RecursiveDirectoryItorator, but I found that for some reason some of my variables are out of scope when they should be in scope... unless I'm really missing something. the two variables I'm trying to access are the $master_array, and the $current, both of witch do not have any values if i echo or print_r them in my else statement. here is my code:

```
$master_array = array(); 

$startpath = "some file path"; // i'm using a real file path in my code. 
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($startpath), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST); 

foreach($ritit as $fileinfo) {
    echo "<pre>"; 
    $current = ''; 
    if(!$fileinfo->isFile()) {

        if(strip_replace($fileinfo->getFilename()) == strip_replace('some  - title')) {
            $master_array[$fileinfo->getFilename()]  = $fileinfo->getPathname(); 
            $current = $fileinfo->getFilename(); 
        } 

    } else {

        if(!empty($current) && in_array($current, split_file_path_into_array($fileinfo->getPathname()))) {
            echo $fileinfo->getFilename()."\n"; 
            echo $fileinfo->getPathname()."\n"; 
        } 
        echo $current; // i don't have access to this
        print_r($master_array); // and i don't have access to this.  

        }
    }
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I hope I'm just overlooking something simple, but I've been looking at this code, and messing with it for quite some time, and can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$current` should be array not string

```
$current = array();
```

And `$current` will always be empty because you are calling it inside else and assigning value inside `if's if`.

Comment: i tried that... it does nothing. an example of the fact that it does not work is that I even tried to print out the $master_array... which prints out a value if I ether call it in the if statement or outside of the else statement. so I'm really confused. I appreciate your quick response though.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B. May be your condition never met and results only else part. Try with proper debugging.

Comment: I agree with your statement "$current will always be empty because you are calling it inside else and assigning value inside if's if." that makes sense... but what I don't get now, is why the $master_array has no value, when it has higher scope than the foreach loop. and I will try debugging it... good advice.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B. May be your condition never met and results only else part and it never assigns the value to `$master_array`